# Heroku - Getting page not found - I think I have set a root route too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am following this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org but when I deploy to heroku and use the command `heroku open` I get "the page you were looking for doesn't exist." I have been reading around and it seems that everyone's issues involved not setting a root route. I added this line to the beginning of my config/routes.rb file:

```
root 'users#index'
```

but to now avail. I committed, pushed to heroku and migrated the db after too. Any ideas?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

Maybe I didn't create them correctly? Capital letters or something?

Here is my routes.rb:

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'users#index'

  resources :microposts

  resources :users

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Here is my heroku logs:

```
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3113425911459750945__call__callbacks'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/rub
y/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3113425911459750945__call__callbacks'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.454935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-
07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.455521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456850+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.457227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-07T08:00:40.458180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Hmm... so not that then...

Comment: I know it's a lot of code but can you post your routes.rb? you can delete the controller as it's not helpful. I'm assuming there's just an ```end``` missing in the controller code pasted and it's there in the real code.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like I cleared all the normal bugs seen. But then why am I still getting ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController): in the logs

Comment: also - just to get the dumb questions out of the way - you've definitely committed the change that added the UsersController and pushed that code up to Heroku, and not just have it locally... in fact  does this work locally when you run ```rails s``` and look at localhost?

Comment: Where's your controller code?

Comment: controller was fine @zeantsoi

Comment: so root should be the last entry in your routes file - not sure this changes what you're seeing but it should be

Comment: yeah, it works flawlessly locally. I used git add . 
git commit -m "<some new message>"  
git push
git push heroku 
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku open

Comment: so correct me if i'm wrong but git commit -m alone doesn't commit

Comment: It won't let me add multiline comment, I am getting the proper feedback at each step too

Comment: shouldn't you have done ```git commit -am``` ? I need to go check that now in my git cheat sheet... but i thought that just doing git commit -m wouldn't actually commit files from staging but just set hte message

Comment: the controller code you posted before wasn't the whole file was it? because lines were missing... just the main part?

Comment: @RichardJordan, the controller is precisely the problem. OP is missing resource actions for the users resource routes.

Comment: I was actually using both and neither worked. git -a -m "<message>" is just shorthand for git add . and then git commit -m "<message>"

Comment: @zeantsoi it looked like a scaffolded controller when it was posted - mharris7190 when you posted it there were lines missing off the bottom of the controller - was that just a cut and paste fail or is zeantsoi right and you don't have those in the controller?

Comment: actually, yeah it was just a cut and paste fail, the full users controller is listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran

`rake assets:precompile`

before committing and pushing and everything is working now. GAW!! :P

Comment: This will not have resolve the issue as described in the question – something else must have happened. I would recommend you remove this answer (or question, altogether) as it warrants downvoting, IMO.

Comment: I consistently get the same error whenever I forget to precompile assets on new projects. After I remember to precompile, it works...

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you there's no UsersController - have you set this up?

```
2014-02-07T08:00:40.456085+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):
```

I see you have the file - but is there a typo on the line

```
class UsersController << ApplicationController
```

or anything like that. Uninitialized constant means that for some reason there isn't a loaded constant - class or module in this case - called UsersController. Most commonly this is just a typo or missing file.

Comment: Can you paste the code from UsersController?  Is there maybe a typo in the ```class UsersController << ApplicationController``` line or something?

Comment: did u have index method m/d inside Users controller

Comment: ```uninitialized constant UsersController``` wouldn't be to do with the ```#index``` method though - it's more often a typo like ```class UserController``` or something... at least that's often been the mistake I've made which has led to this error

Comment: I'll add UsersController in OP

Answer (score 0):

This class name in the users controller may have been spelt incorrectly. It should probably be something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```